# Getting Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, promise

There's a form in which I have to validate a field if it exists in the DB or not.

Below is my code :

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const [isDSB, setIsDSB] = useState(true)

const getDSB = (dsb, token) => { // returns a Promise
  return axios.get(`${endpoints.root}/${dsb}`, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  })
}

const validateInsertForm = (fields) => {
  
  getDSB(fields.dsb)
    .then((resp) => {
      if(!resp.data.isAvailable){
        setIsDSB(false)
      }
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.error(e)
    })

    if(!isDSB){
      return {
        isValid: false,
        error: {
          field: 'dsb',
          errorMessage: 'DSB does not exist'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am getting invalid hook call here. I tried using a `let` variable but that doesn't change the state inside the getDSB call. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just as the error states, you can only invoke hooks from inside a component or another hook.  You're trying to call `useState` at the module level, not inside of a component or hook.

Answer (score 0):

Offical React docs says:

> Only Call Hooks from React Functions
> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.
> Instead, you can call Hooks from React function components or
> call Hooks from custom Hooks

So in your example you are using hooks inside JavaScript function.
To fix that just create functional component, and use hooks inside